# PostGIS Spatial Query to calculate an average

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-statistics

I am currently working on a project that requires me to calculate average pollution levels for a large amount of point data. The image below shows the focus area (in green). My task is to calculate the average pollution for the postcode areas (polygons in black beneath the focus area) for any contained or part-contained in this area.

[image]

The point data and the areas both have geometries associated with them. I have been working on various queries for a while now, but everytime I enter a spatial element to the query it is bringing back a blank table:

```py
SELECT p.id,
ROUND (AVG(n."2011"),2) AS Aveage_NO2_2011
FROM postcode_area p, no2_2011 n
WHERE ST_WITHIN (n.geom, p.geom)
GROUP BY p.id;
```

The aim is to produce a cholopleth map for the postcode areas of the mean NO2 levels. This should exclude any postcode areas that do not intersect or are not contained within the focus area.

Comment: I have now executed a spatial join on the data in QGIS, so I now have a table with repeating postcodes and the NO2 levels. I need to average the NO2 by postcode but cannot figure out how to do this within QGIS.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to add new details. Comments should be reserved for others to ask for clarification. You should always specify the exact version of software in use. The are many fine books and web pages that show how to properly join tables, and they all use the `JOIN` operator. In your case you should focus on the difference between `ST_Intersects` and `ST_Intersection`. Note that *active* NOT operations are generally far more expensive to perform, but not drawing where no data exists is trivial.

Comment: @Vince Actually, I have struggled for the 3 years I've been using PostGIS to find documentation on the use of the syntax that this question is asking. Whenever I give workshops, people ask where to find it, and the only good source of this type of syntax is GIS.SE. You're right when you say there is documentation, but it is missing the use cases that are described in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that will sum up the **aland10** field from the zip codes at the county level

```
select 
c.geoid
, cast(avg(z.aland10) as decimal(10,2)) as "Average"
from denver.zip_codes as z
join denver.county as c on ST_Intersects(ST_Centroid(z.geom), c.geom)
group by c.geoid
```

Note that I'm converting the polygons of the ZIP_Codes to their centroid and intersecting them rather than within - I'm only interested in intersecting the points to the county.

If you wanted to count the # of points, you would add that in too:

```
select 
c.geoid
, cast(avg(z.aland10) as decimal(10,2)) as "Average"
, count(*) as "CountZips"
from denver.zip_codes as z
join denver.county as c on ST_Intersects(ST_Centroid(z.geom), c.geom)
group by c.geoid
```

Note on using ST_Intersects with the centroids versus ST_Intersection to 'clip' the polygons that fall within the County - Seems ST_Intersection would give just the remaining polygon area that fell within the county - if that's appropriate to cut off sections of the zip codes, that is up to you...

Comment: shouldn't you add in ST_INTERSECTION on the study area and zipcodes because some of the zipcodes are only partially within the study area?

Comment: @ziggy If indeed that's how they should be 'clipped' - but that opens up a can of worms as to how to handle the value assigned to the area (ie clipping blockgroups and estimating remaining population...) but good to note regardless!

Comment: yeah i guess if she only needs the average pollution per zip code then you do not need it

Comment: Be careful with `ST_Centroid` and census data -- `ST_PointOnSurface` takes longer, but the generated point can't be outside the source polygon (falling in lakes and whatnot, which will hose the statistics)

Comment: @Vince yes, we've tried that - luckily all our analysis and data lines up just fine, but good to have in the back pocket!